# Update Links message from MS-Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, updates

I have an MS-Excel Workbook that links to another for data. The links update when the book is opened, but I still get this message "This workbook contains one or more links that cannot be updated."  You get Continue or Edit Links options.  I want to disable this message or prevent it from appearing, how do I do that?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to a spreadsheet, or some other application?  Which application are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I mentioned Excel spreadsheets somewhere.

Comment: I updated your question accordingly, including the tags.  The "microsoft-excel" tag should bring a little bit more attention to your question from those who are more likely to know of some solutions.  Welcome to SuperUser.com!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From MSDN -

> 1. On Edit menu, click Links. *Note In
>      Excel 2007, click Edit Links in the
>      Connections group on the Data tab.*
> 2. Click Startup Prompt.
> 3. Click the Don't display the alert and
>      don't update automatic links option.

Here is the link for more info - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826921

Comment: Thankyou Ben. In combination with your tip and some playing round with a Workbook_open event so the data updates, it works. Thanks